Why is the formula for nickel selenide NiSe rather than Ni2Se?
I am learning about ionic bonding & how to write chemical formulas for ionic compounds.
A practice problem asks me to find the chemical formula for nickel selenide.
My approach is as follows:
Since nickel's electron configuration is $\ce{[Ar] 3d^8}$, nickel will have a more stable electron configuration if it either gains 2 electrons or loses 3.
Since selenium's electron configuration is $\ce{[Ar] 3d^10 4s^2 4p^4}$, selenium will have a more stable electron configuration if it either gains 2 electrons or loses 4.
Because 2 nickel atoms want to gain 4 electrons while 1 selenium atom wants to lose 4 electrons, it follows that the most stable nickel selenide compound is $\ce{Ni2Se}$.
This is the kind of reasoning I have used to get correct answers for similar problems, but this reasoning fails here. My guess is that it has something to do with the $\ce{4s^2}$ orbital in the nickel. Maybe the nickel atom would prefer to lose the 2 electrons in the $\ce{4s^2}$ orbital rather than gain 2/lose 3 for the d orbital. But I don't understand why this would be the case.

$\ce{NiSe}$ is usually nonstoichiometric and is often described with the formula $\ce{Ni_{1−x}Se}$, with 0 < x < 0.15

The Ni-Se phase diagram shows 5 intermediate phases: a low temperature and a high temperature phase for Ni3Se2, Ni6Se5, the mentioned NiSe, and finally NiSe2. Attempting to use atomic configurations for solid state phases is not particularly useful.

As Nilay Ghosh indicates in a comment, nickel selenide is usually not stoichiometric, and it is not completely ionic. That being so, you should consider the following:

Transition metals generally do not seek a $d^5$ or $d^{10}$ electron configuration in forming binary compounds. Among elements in the first transition metals, only $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ commonly achieve the $d^5$ configuration in binary compounds, and only $\ce{Cu+}$ and $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ commonly achieve $d^{10}$. With other metals the relative stability of these configurations is overwhelmed by ionization energies being too high or too low to strike a good energy balance.

Most first-row transition metals tend to favor +2 or +3 ions because of this ionization energy balance, regardless of how many $d$ electrons this leaves. For later transition elements such as Ni we typically see +2.

Selenium is in a column close to the noble gases, so think about gaining electrons. Elements in selenium's column can achieve a stable noble gas configuration by gaining two electrons, which they commonly do when combined with metals.


Thus in this case, if we had a stoichiometric ionic compound at all for nickel and selenium, it would be $\ce{Ni^{2+}, Se^{2-}}\implies \ce{NiSe}$.

As pointed out at the beginning, nickel selenides are not truly ionic and the proposed nickel selenide is not stoichiometric. Zobač et al. [1] give a phase diagram showing several nickel selenides, none entirely conforming with the modeled result above:

From this diagram it is true that the approximate $\ce{NiSe}$ composition, with its nickel-deficient non-stoichiometry, is the most stable species in the sense that it has the highest melting point and all others decompose to form it before they would have melted completely. (We say that only the $\ce{Ni_{1-x}Se}$ phase melts congruently.) Given that selenide ion is rather easy to oxidize, the nickel deficiency is probably made up by having some selenium atoms gain one electron instead of two, leaving electron holes that make this a $p$-type semiconductor.
Reference

Zobač, O., Buchlovská, K., Pavlů, J. et al. "Thermodynamic Description of Binary System Nickel-Selenium". J. Phase Equilib. Diffus. 42, 468–478 (2021). https://doi.org/10.1007/s11669-021-00906-9


Sorry, most of this goes far over my head (I am just starting to learn chemistry), but thank you for the detailed reply. My understanding is that nickel prefers to lose 2 electrons rather than gain 2 because it requires less ionisation energy? Is there a relatively simple way to understand why it requires less ionisation energy?
